# Using SQL Server 2008 BCP utility to export a stored procedure (simple select)

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, bcp

I am trying to run the `BCP` utility from SQL Server 2008.

I created a very simple stored procedure called `GET_GL_ACCOUNTS`

here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_GL_ACCOUNTS]
AS
     SELECT DISTINCT 
         RTRIM (s1.SGMNTID) AS 'AccCode',
         RTRIM (s1.DSCRIPTN) AS 'CodeDesc', 
         CASE
            WHEN  s1.SGMTNUMB = '1' THEN '1' 
            WHEN s1.SGMTNUMB = '2' THEN '2'
            WHEN s1.SGMTNUMB = '3' THEN '110'
            WHEN s1.SGMTNUMB = '4' THEN '4'
            WHEN s1.SGMTNUMB = '5' THEN '120'
         END AS 'AccountType_id',
         CASE 
            WHEN s1.SGMTNUMB = '2' THEN LEFT(s1.SGMNTID, 2)
            ELSE 'DEFAULT'
         END AS 'AccGroupName'
     FROM 
         GL40200 s1

     UNION 

     SELECT  
         REPLACE ([ACTNUMBR_1]+'-'+ [ACTNUMBR_2]+'-'+ [ACTNUMBR_3]+'-'+[ACTNUMBR_4]+'-'+  [ACTNUMBR_5],' ', '') AS 'AccCode',
         '' AS 'CodeDesc',
         '0' AS 'AccountType_id',
         'Default' AS 'AccGroupName'
     FROM 
         GL00100 a
```

Here is my `BCP` command:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp 'EXEC NCOA.dbo.GET_GL_ACCOUNTS' QUERYOUT "E:\dbexport\gl.txt"  -c -t, -T -S'
```

When I execute this through SQL Server Management Studio I am getting the following error message:

> Msg 8146, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GET_GL_ACCOUNTS, Line 0
>   Procedure GET_GL_ACCOUNTS has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Do I need parameters and arguments to run this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your issue is how the statement is quoted. Try this instead:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "EXEC NCOA.dbo.GET_GL_ACCOUNTS" QUERYOUT "E:\dbexport\gl.txt"  -c -t, -T -S'
```

Comment: That is producing this output
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file
NULL

(3 row(s) affected)

Comment: @ShawnRahmani Is the path `E:\dbexport\gl.txt` valid on the server you're executing the code on (the maching running sql server)? The error message suggest that it might not be.

Comment: This ended up being a folder permissions issue. When I moved the eport to my backup folder it works. Thank you @jpw